# Does Unity generally perform better with proprietary Nvidia drivers?

Tags: unity, nvidia

I always feel stressed when updating or switching to proprietary drivers, because it has crashed my Ubuntu before. Unity is a little slow on my system. Can switching to a new version of proprietary drivers speed it up some day?

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is a smoother experience (depending on which Nvidia card you have) although the Nouveau driver is definitely improving.

Have you/are you willing to try unity-2d?  It should run much more smoothly for you

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the window manager itself does not perform better, but the applications do. This is most notable with any graphics intense , 3d application or games.

I try to stay with the open source drivers for the same reasons you do.

If the open source driver is causing you a problem, try the nvidia driver, you can always revert.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my proprietary driver is smoother than open source driver. Extremely on games/3d applications.

I have not any problem on installing Nvidia proprietary driver!
Following procedure is what i used for installing Nvidia driver:

1. Download appropriate current driver from [NVidia.com](http://www.Nvidia.com)
2. Copy downloaded driver into Desktop
3. Right-click on it and under **Permissions** tab active **Execute** check box
4. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to switch to tty1
5. Loggin and **stop LightDM** service using `sudo service lightdm stop`
6. Goto desktop folder and run Nvidia driver using following commands: (notice that my Nvidia driver is `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-285.05.09.run`)  
   `cd ~/Desktop`
   `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-285.05.09.run`
7. It will notify you to problem on installing driver and will asks you to uninstalling Nouveau driver. Also it will asks *"Do you want to disabling Nouveau driver?"*
   Let it to do that.
   Again it will prompt you to unsuccessful installation. Don't worry, it is OK... reboot your machine using `sudo reboot`
8. Now your resolution is 800x600. It's OK.
   Repeat step 4 ~ 6 and complete installation procedure and **let it to auto configure X**
9. **Reboot** or start LightDM service using `sudo service lightdm start` command

Enjoy! :)